# main.pyでimportしているモジュールからmain.pyで定義されている関数を呼び出す方法はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3

よろしくお願いいたします。

以下のようなことを実現したいのですが、main.pyで定義されているfun()をmain.pyがimportしているsub.pyから呼び出したいのですが、やり方はあるのでしょうか？

```
# main.py
from sub.py import *
def fun():
    print('test')
call_fun() # 'test'を表示したい
```

```
# sub.py
def call_fun():
    fun() # ここで自分をimportしているmain.pyのfun()を呼び出したい。うまい書き方はるのでしょうか？
```

funをcall_fun()に渡せば（例、call_fun(fun)）できそうですが、それはしたくないのです。

また、sub.pyをimportするファイル名は、好きなものにしたいので、例えば、main.pyをmain2.pyにしても動くようにしたいのです。sub.pyのcall_fun()はどのように書けば実現できるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

[Is there a way to access parent modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286210/9014308)
上記記事の以下の回答を応用すれば出来るようです。
ただし、多段階の`import`とかされると適用できないかもしれませんね。

> [For posterity, I ran into this also and came up with the one liner:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45895490/9014308)
>
> ```
> import sys
> parent_module = sys.modules['.'.join(__name__.split('.')[:-1]) or '__main__']
> ```
>
> The `or '__main__'` part is just in case you load the file directly it will return itself.

ソースコードは以下のようになるでしょう。

- `main.py`は`sub.py`を`import`する行を以下に変える。(`.py`を削る)

```
from sub import *
```

- `sub.py`は上記記事を応用して親モジュールの情報を取得しておき、その関数を呼び出す。

```
# sub.py
import sys
parent_module = sys.modules['.'.join(__name__.split('.')[:-1]) or '__main__']

def call_fun():
    parent_module.fun() # ここで自分をimportしている親モジュールのfun()を呼び出す。
```

Comment: 素晴らしいです T^T)/ ありがとうございます。
半日、悩んでないですぐにPOSTすればよかったです。

Comment: 自身がなにかのパッケージのサブモジュールだったら一つ親を、そうでなければ `__main__` を、という処理だと思いますが意図通りですか? 単に `parent_module = sys.modules['__main__']` の方が合ってませんか?

Comment: @quickquip さん、その辺が最初の方に書いた懸念事項ですね。質問では`main.py`と`sub.py`しか示されなかったので、明確に`__main__`つまりルートモジュールの関数なのか、それともmainのmain(祖父的なモジュール?)→main→subという風に多段階になる時があるのか、その時にどちらの関数を呼びたいのかは読み取れなかったので。見つけた関連しそうな記事をそのまま使用してみました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上にたどる場合もあるのでありがたいです。